# Django, How to enforce model Foreinkeys to have same value

Tags: django

In Django I want to enforce that a model which has two foreinkeys of differents models which has the same type of field to be the same, in example:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField(max_length=48)

class Model2(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField(max_length=48)

class Model3(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
```

I want that creation of objects of Model3 would be made only if f1 field of Model1 and Model2 are the same. (Edit: please note that each model has other fields that are not relavant to the question)

Comment: In that case, I think something is a bit "off" with your modeling, since this looks like *data duplication*.

Comment: Hi, in my real models each model has other fields that are not related to other models, those fields are not relavnt to the question there for I didnt mention them

Comment: but then you should probably *factor out* this field in a separate model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this isn't possible at a db level. However, you could enforce it at the code level fairly easily through a pre-save signal. pre-save signals in django allow you to perform an operation/check before a model is actually saved to the database.

See the below example for a potential solution.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save)
def pre_save_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
  if instance.field1.f1 != instance.field2.f2:
      raise Exception('Cannot save models, because their values do not match!')
```

Here we are checking if the fields have the same value, and if they don't an exception is thrown, keeping the record from saving.